# Marker is not displayed on HERE Map

Tags: android-studio, maps, here-api

I want a Marker to be displayed on the Map, but it's not displayed, here's the code I used,
I'm using HERE Map SDK for Android

```
Image img = new Image();
                try {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.marker);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MapMarker mm = new MapMarker();
                mm.setIcon(img);
                mm.setCoordinate(new GeoCoordinate(21.609512, 39.131269));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the MapMarker, you need to add it also to your map via Map.addMapObject(...)

See my example (where mMap is my instance of Map, and the anchor point is on the botton instead of center):

```
    private void addMarker(GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate) 
    {
        if (mMarker == null) {
            Image image = new Image();
            try {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.pin);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mMarker = new MapMarker(geoCoordinate, image);
            mMarker.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()));
            mMap.addMapObject(mMarker);
        } else {
            mMarker.setCoordinate(geoCoordinate);
        }
        mMap.setCenter(geoCoordinate, Animation.BOW);
    }
```